# CreateProxy для Android (LuaJava)

Tags: android, lua, listener

Есть у меня Lua функция `Button`, которая создает кнопку, добавляет её на layout и возвращает саму кнопку. Затем я хочу добавить к нему `ClickListener`

```
local button = Button("text", MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
button:setOnClickListener(luajava.createProxy("android.view.View.OnClickListener", {
        onClick = function (e)
            print("clicked")
        end
    }
))
```

Но в ответ получаю только это:

```
Runtime error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/View/OnClickListener
stack trackback:
[C]: in function 'createProxy'
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось банально просто.

1-е. Вместо собственной функции `Button`, можно использовать:

```
local btn = luajava.newInstance("android.widget.Button", activity:getApplicationContext())
btn:setText("text")
layout:addView(btn)
```

Так, я думаю, будет правильнее.

2-е. `createProxy` не мог найти класс из-за его неправильного пути. Правильным будет `android.view.View$OnClickListener`:

```
btn:setOnClickListener(luajava.createProxy("android.view.View$OnClickListener", {
        onClick = function (e)
            print("clicked")
        end
    }
))
```